# simultaneously moving a file and changing permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, mv

In Linux, when I use mv, the new file retains the same permissions.  I would like to mv a file, but after the move, by the owner of the new file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by simultaneous and why does it matter? Would this work for you?

For permissions:

```
mv $old $new; chmod xyz $new
```

For owner:

```
mv $old $new; chown user:user $new
```

Comment: +1, but since the OP wants to be the owner, you better change `chmod xyz` to `chown $USER $new`

Comment: Was confused by the title & the text being different!

Comment: So, this doesn't work because the file I am using mv on is not owned by me so I cannot chown it unless I am root

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the reason, are there any workarounds other than adding a line into sudoers?

Answer (score 0):

You can `mv` and then `chown` the file in the same terminal line. See [Executing multiple command in sequence](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#multiple).